# How to create multiple Tkinter windows when clicking a button with classes being read in multiple files?

Tags: python, tkinter

Recently I have been developing a python gui using Tkinter and my code is getting very long and hard to follow. Therefore, I have decided to break it up into different files for the different pages on the program. I have a short version of the code which seems to work for the first time I try to access page one but after I go back to the main menu it gives me an error saying that I haven't defined the function.

Main.py

```py
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except:
    import tkinter as tk

from PageOne import *


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(StartPage)
        self.title('hey there')
        self.geometry('1000x1000')

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Label(self, text="Start page", font=('Helvetica', 18, "bold")).pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=5)
        tk.Button(self, text="Go to Start Page", command=lambda: master.switch_frame(Page_One)).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Go to page two", command=lambda: master.switch_frame(PageTwo)).pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Frame.configure(self, bg='blue')
        tk.Label(self, text="Page one", font=('Helvetica', 18, "bold")).pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=5)
        tk.Button(self, text="Go back to start page",
                  command=lambda: master.switch_frame(StartPage)).pack()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Frame.configure(self, bg='red')
        tk.Label(self, text="Page two", font=('Helvetica', 18, "bold")).pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=5)
        tk.Button(self, text="Go back to start page", command=lambda: master.switch_frame(StartPage)).pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

PageOne.py

```py
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except:
    import tkinter as tk

from main import StartPage

class Page_One(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Frame.configure(self, bg='blue')
        tk.Label(self, text="Page one", font=('Helvetica', 18, "bold")).pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=5)
        tk.Button(self, text="Go back to start page", command=lambda: master.switch_frame(StartPage)).pack()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be due to circular import which should be avoided.

Try changing `switch_frame()` function as below:

```py
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    ...
    def switch_frame(self, frame_class=None):
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = frame_class(self) if frame_class else StartPage(self)
        self._frame.pack()
    ...
```

Then in `PageOne.py`, don't import `main` and call `switch_frame()` without argument:

```py
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except:
    import tkinter as tk

class Page_One(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Frame.configure(self, bg='blue')
        tk.Label(self, text="Page one", font=('Helvetica', 18, "bold")).pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=5)
        tk.Button(self, text="Go back to start page", command=master.switch_frame).pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with this line:

```
self._frame = new_frame
```

You are passing a **class** into switch_frame, but you want to call `pack` on an *instance*.

There are two ways to fix this.

1. Call master.switch_frame(StartPage()))
2. Change the line above to `self._frame = new_frame()`

(Notice the `()` in both cases).

Your second problem is that this pattern can't work:

```
 master.switch_frame(StartPage())).pack()
```

This is because your function `switch_frame` doesn't have a return value. Therefore there is nothing that the code can pack! Again you have some choices:

1. Change the code to `master.switch_frame(StartPage()))`
2. Have `switch_frames` end with `self._frame = new_frame; return self._frame` instead of including `.pack()` in that function.

It should be noted that you are probably better off using `master.switch_frame(StartPage()))` (without the `.pack()`). This is because you probably don't *want* the application to give the rest of the code access to your current `_frame` value.

Comment: Could you send me the correct version, I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: No. That's really not something I can do. You need to make architectural decisions on this.